# Zooming out the map gives a wrong lat long android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am sorry if I cant explain the situation with my topic but here is the issue..

I have custom marker (Imageview) on google maps whenever I tap the marker it retrieves the address and display in a textView .. When I completely zoom in Map and tap the marker it gives the EXACTLY correct address BUT when I zoom out , it still gives the address but this time 1 or 2 block further from the exact point of my marker.. So confusing , Can anybody help me about what is wrong?

Here is my code

```
    OnTouchListener imgSourceOnTouchListener
= new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        LatLng center = map.getCameraPosition().target;


        String filterAddress = "";
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    center.latitude, 
                    center.longitude, 1);

            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                for (int index = 0; 
                index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                    filterAddress += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
            }
        }catch (IOException ex) {        
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e2) {
            // TODO: handle exception

            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        touchedXY.setText(String.valueOf("address" +filterAddress));

        return true;


    }
};
```

Comment: as it is shown here you are printing the address of the position of the camera not the position of the marker in your onTouch method

Comment: So? What am I supposed to do can you explain in detail..

Comment: Also I've defined marker in class like that .. imgSource1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.view);
   imgSource1.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);  I think this provide me to print the marker position isn it ??

Comment: hmm so you said that when I tap on marker it gives me the address in respect to camera position , it is not related with marker .. Hmm I've tought that it was markers position .. How can I implement it do you have any idea

Comment: maybe you should think about another approach to what you want to do since you are having so much trouble trying to use a static image overlayed on the map. then you wouldnt have to create the same relative question over and over again

Comment: @tyczj you do not need to look at my topics .. If you know a solution related with the issue you can just share instead of judging me here.. once I've requested a detailed help from you and you just said "try yourself".. So as I said I think this shouldnt be bothering you

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't use Marker in this way `imgSource1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.view);` 
Markers should be added in Java code not from referencing it from xml file by id as you said.
you have to set `setOnMapClickListener`

```
 map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {fromMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(arg0));   }
        });
```

Now there is a **Marker** will be placed where you touch the map you can use this marker to show the address, so zooking or changing the camera position will not change the addres location that you pressed

Comment: I know but in my scenario marker is an ImageView because I want to set it in the center of screen and when I move the map it shouldnt be disappear .. In marker that I've added with java code it got disappear when I move the map to another place, making Imageview as a marker provide me stability on map .. Do you know any other option to do this with normal marker ? not the custom one ..thanks for your help.

Comment: If i understood what you want then you can put in your OnMapClickListener you replace `fromMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(arg0)); ` with ` if (fromMarker ==null){fromMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(arg0)); } else{fromMarker.setPosition(arg0);}` this will update the position of the marker while you are moving the marker and it will not be removed

Comment: Here is what I exactly want to do please notify me if you have any other idea in your mind thanks a lot .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407202/android-retrieving-current-position-on-mapsv2-dynamically

Comment: I've tried your second advise this just adds a marker on current position.. what is crucial here is to have a marker on the center of map but when you move the map it has to keep its position stable where ever you pan the map I always have to see the marker.. Thats why I've used ImageView

Comment: what i said in last comment solves your problem by adding the part of getting the address from the Geocoder after setting the marker position and i think this what  you want. you want the marker to be in the center of the map always, and the above textBox contains the address of the marker which is the center of the map !!

Comment: You can make your own **TouchWrapper** which detects the motion of the map, in motion start you remove the marker and on motion end you show the marker after updating its position and update the address in the textView

Comment: Yes In your second comment when I tap the map the marker is placed .. but when I move the map it I couldnt see it , I know it is still there but it has to be always displayed where ever I pan the map .. ARRGHH this really kills me I am completely newbie for android and making my own TouchWrapper would be tough for me . Is there resource for that how to implement it? or at least can you provide me a little piece of code it would be a boost for me .. Thanks anyway if not I appreciate for your time and interest.. btw have you check the link that I've provided